# Eclipse Unable To Import Java Libraries

Tags: eclipse

Some, not all, java projects in eclipse are giving me an error because the import command is not recognized. It is really weird because only some projects are having this error. For instance:

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

In Eclipse a red line appears under java.util.Arrays or  java.lang.reflect and Eclipse gives the error: The import java.util cannot be resolved. or The import java.lang cannot be resolved
It must be a configuration of Eclipse because Netbeans does not give the error.
I am new to using Eclipse. Thanks for any help.
Mike

Comment: Which Java version have you configured in the project and what do you have in the preferences in _Java > Installed JREs_?

Comment: I believe you answered my question. Thanks. I checked and yes that is the problem.